# WPF App.xaml in different Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

I want to setup a WPF Application. But instead of using the entry point of the application to a App.xaml itself, I've to projects.

The first projects is a Windows Application and has a normale Main function. And I've an additional project (WPF control library), that has the App.xaml, windows, controls and all it needs.

The main method start the Application like this:

> ```
> [STAThread]
> static void Main()
> {
>      Application.Run();
> }
> ```

Where Application is a class in the library:

> ```
> public static class Application
> {
>       public void Run()
>       {
>             App app = new App();
>             app.Run();
>       }
> }
> ```

Where app is my App.xaml. App.xaml defines a startup uri `MainWindow.xaml`. But if I run the application, the window is never displayed, but the application itself runs.

I can not setup the App.xaml in the first assembly, because I've to support multiple window frameworks (WPF, Gtk#, etc). Any suggestions how to manage this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
app.InitializeComponent();
```

between `App app = new App();` and `app.Run();`.

Comment: It works, but its only a work around, because we setup the main window for the application manually (like `App.Run(new MainWindow())` would do). But the App.xaml itself is still not used. You can try this, if you add resources to the App.xaml and use them inside the window.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the post: `app.MainWindow = ...` really was a simple workaround

Comment: `InitializeComponent` loads everything from xaml