# When running WPF app from console app, App.xaml is ignored

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Suppose I've created a WPF application, let's call it `TestApplication`, using the default template in Visual Studio 2019, i.e. I'm set up with an `App.xaml`, `App.xaml.cs`, `MainWindow.xaml`, and `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

I'm then trying to run this WPF application programmatically from a console application in a different assembly through

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new TestApplication.App();
    app.Run();
}
```

Now, this won't quite work on itself. The [first part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794422/5085211) provides one alternative approach: If I change `app.Run()` to `app.Run(new TestApplication.MainWindow())`, then `MainWindow` is actually opened.

However, this looks like it should be necessary: By default, `App.xaml` includes in its definition of `<Application />` a `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`, which would suggest that it should somehow be able to find `MainWindow` on its own.

More generally, `App.xaml` seems to be ignored entirely through this approach; in my setup, I've included a collection of `ResourceDictionary` in `App.xaml`, and they simply won't get loaded.

So, is there some way to run a WPF application programmatically that takes into account the contents of the XAML?

Edit: After playing around a bit, I realized that `InitializeComponent` is responsible for handling this for windows and user controls. As suggested also by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4482747/5085211), changing the above code to

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new TestApplication.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

does indeed take me one step further, but I'm then left with a

> **System.IO.IOException**: 'Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.'

I could imagine this happens because the relative paths don't resolve properly when in a different assembly, but it doesn't provide much of a hint on how to solve the issue.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I just meant that then a window is actually opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's sufficient to also manually overwrite `Application.StartupUri` as follows:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new TestApplication.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.StartupUri = new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/TestApplication;component/{app.StartupUri}");
    app.Run();
}
```

While not the most satisfying solution in the world, it does appear to do the job in that all other relative paths in `App.xaml` are translated as expected; in particular, if I include in `App.xaml` a `ResourceDictionary` with a `Source` of, say, `Style.xaml`, then this is picked up properly by the console application as well.